# What are monocytes with vacoules called?

Tags: cell-biology, immune-system

I've heard that monocytes sometimes appear with vacuoles. Do monocytes with a vacuole have a name? If so, do monocytes without a vacuole have a name as well?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you’re sure that you’re looking at a monocyte, then I don’t think there is a difference in nomenclature here. But normally monocytes aren’t very phagocytic, they leave most of that to when they differentiate into macrophages.

This is further seen in blood smears. A monocyte’s cytoplasm isn’t quite vacuolated, implying that there isn’t very much phagocytosis going on; but is granular due to the presence of lysosomes awaiting fusion with phagosomes, and the lysosomes in this case are actually called “azurophilic granules”.

Comment: I think this is a helpful answer, but it would be good to include citations, linked sources, or illustrations.